# Comparar un string en todas su variables (mayúsculas, minúsculas, mixto)

Tags: javascript, string

Necesito hacer un algoritmo que censure las palabras obscenas, según la *consigna*, debe censurar la palabra que esté completamente en minúsculas, mayúsculas o una mezcla de ambas.

¿Hay alguna manera de que un `if` detecte una palabra sin importar el tipo de letra?

Comment: Hola Franco, deberías indicar qué es lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte mejor. ¿cómo estás haciendo el `if`? ¿cómo comparas las cadenas? ¿estás usando expresiones regulares? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución simple es tener un diccionario y si la palabra la pasas a minúscula, con esto realizas un estándar en la evaluación. Luego revisas si esta en el diccionario de filtro, si se encuentra entonces retorna verdadero, en caso contrario retorna falso.

```
function filtrarPalabras(palabra) {
   let diccionarioFiltrar = ['palabra1', 'palabra2', 'palabra3'];
   if (diccionarioFiltrar.indexOf(palabra.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```